# Varnish ban stays in banlist forever

Tags: caching, varnish, ttl

I have a varnishsetup (Varnish 3) running on a developmentserver and the same setup on a productionserver.
The developmentserver does not get any traffic unless I test on it.
The productionserver gets a lot of traffic of about 80 websites going through that varnishinstance. The websites are quite the same, so one VCL for all of them is fine.

Currently I am testing with URL smart-bans and the ban_lurker.

What I am expecting is that when I add a ban, even if the ban would not work for some reason, it should stay there in the banlist only for the largest TTL in my cache + backend-response-grace-period.

**The problem**

The problem is that on my productionserver instead the ban stays in the banlist forever (or at least for 24 hours since that's the time I've given it to be gone).

So I've tweaked my VCL so that I'd expect that it is impossible for any cache-object to stay longer in cache than 20 minutes, since I force that 20 minutes from my vcl_fetch and force beresp.grace to 0s.

On my development varnishserver this seems to work exactly like that. When I click through the website and cache some stuff that way, then put a ban in, it is gone in 20 minutes as expected.
On my productionserver this seems to have no effect on the banlist at all. It just stays there.

Do I miss something there??

**The VCL**

Could someone please take a look at my VCL and tell me what I am doing wrong?
Note that I left out some stuff like the backend configuration and the purge/ban config because I think that does not matter right now. Correct me if I'm wrong :)

```
import std;

# Define backends
include "backends.vcl";

# Define recv basics
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.request != "GET" &&
      req.request != "HEAD" &&
      req.request != "PUT" &&
      req.request != "POST" &&
      req.request != "TRACE" &&
      req.request != "OPTIONS" &&
      req.request != "DELETE" &&
      req.request != "PURGE" &&
      req.request != "BAN") {
        /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
        return (pipe);
    }
}

# Define purging and banning rules
include "purging-banning.vcl";

# Appart from PURGE and BAN requests, we only handle GET and HEAD requests
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
        /* We only deal with GET and HEAD by default */
        return (pass);
    }

    # Never cache monitor.php
    if (req.url ~ "^/monitor.php") {
         return (pass);
    }

    # in case of down backends serve content up to 30 minutes old
    if (req.backend.healthy) {
        set req.grace = 2m;
    } else {
        set req.grace = 30m;
    }
}

# Define purging and banning rules
include "recv-url-rules.vcl";

# If the URL's hasn't been caught by recv-url-rules.vcl, continue with common rules
sub vcl_recv {   
    # Don't cache AJAX requests
    if (req.http.X-Requested-With == "XMLHttpRequest") {
        return(pass);
    }
}

sub vcl_fetch {
    # Set default TTL of 20 minutes
    set beresp.ttl = 20m;

    # Keep objects in cache beyond their lifetime
    set beresp.grace = 0s; # for testing purposes

    # Don't cache if requested so by the server
    if (beresp.http.X-NoCache  == "no-cache" || beresp.http.cache-control ~ "private") {
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
        set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "max-age = 0";
        return ( hit_for_pass );
    }

    # Pass (don't cache) big files (limit is just under 1MB)
    if ( beresp.http.Content-Length ~ "[0-9]{6,}" ) {
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
        return ( hit_for_pass );
    }

    # Remember URL and HOST for the ban-lurker
    set beresp.http.x-url = req.url;
    set beresp.http.x-host = req.http.host;
}

sub vcl_deliver{
    # These were set for the ban-lurker, but don't have to be send to the client
    unset resp.http.x-url;
    unset resp.http.x-host;

    # Add a header to the request so that we can see wether or not the object came from cache
    if (obj.hits > 0) {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
    } else {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
    }
}

sub vcl_pipe {
    # http://www.varnish-cache.org/ticket/451
    # This forces every pipe request to be the first one.
    set bereq.http.connection = "close";
}
```

**Varnish documentation**

The Varnish documentation states the following:

> Before Varnish runs vcl_fetch, the beresp.ttl variable has already been set to a value. >It will use the first value it finds among:
>
> The s-maxage variable in the Cache-Control response header
>      The max-age variable in the Cache-Control response header
>      The Expires response header
>      The default_ttl parameter.

So is it possible that the TTL is still being overwritten in some cases by the backend response? Even though I force it in vcl_fetch?

Comment: Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 4):

A ban will be kept in the ban list until all objects in cache that are older than it has been checked against it. If you're serving long-tailed content with long TTLs, the banlist will grow very long.

However, since bans are only evaluated once for each object, there is really no downside (besides aesthetics) from this. Don't worry about it.

Comment: As to your second question; see the TTL varnishlog lines. Lines that reference "RFC" are the extracted TTL from the response headers, and lines mentioning "VCL" are your local overrides. Local overrides take precedence.

Comment: Thank you for your answers (sorry I can't upvote yet :( ).
I'm not sure though wether or not you did answer my question. Since I set all TTL to 20 minutes, it wouldn't be possible that the bans stay in any longer than 20 minutes right?

Anyway: I had this problem last week. For some weird reason now suddenly it seems to work completely as expected (the bans are gone pretty quick).
Now I'm going to tweak my TTLs a little bit more with the possibility of a longer banlist instead - which is where your "don't worry about it" comes to mind :)